# Profiling memory usage of background task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I am writing a multimedia app (WP 8.1) which uses BackgroundMediaPlayer. The problem is memory - the background task quite often crashes with OutOfMemoryException. I tried going thru the code to see if there are any memory leaks, but could not find any.

I came across this article which describes memory profiling on running app - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/03/performance-profiling-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio.aspx 
How can the same be achieved for a background task? Or or there other ways to see how I can optimize memory usage of my background task?

I already tried GC.Collect as a last resort, but didn't help..

Comment: The problem isn't a leak, but a hard reference that isn't being released.  The places that I usually find these hiding as they are non-obvious are event handlers attached to memory that you think you have released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the App [Field Medic](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/field-medic/73c58570-d5a7-46f8-b1b2-2a90024fc29c), connect the Phone via USB and open the folder `This PC\Windows Phone\Phone\Documents\FieldMedic\CustomProfiles` in Explorer, creating missing folders in that path as needed.

Download this [profile file](http://mmaitre314.github.io/download/MultimediaMem.wprp), copy it to `CustomProfiles` folder on the Phone.

Start the Field Medic App, go to `advanced`, select the Multimedia Memory Profile under `custom`.

[image]

Now run your App, when you captured several minutes of the memory grow, go back to Field Medic, stop the trace. Copy the ETL file from `This PC\Windows Phone\Phone\Documents\FieldMedic\reports` to your PC and [analyze it with Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc).